# Why do I have an error while compiling my code in C with Qt creator but can easily do this using make file?

Tags: c++, compilation, qt-creator, gstreamer

I use gstreamer in my project, and if I compile program with make - IT WORKS well.

```
SOURCES= \
main.cpp

all: main.cpp
    g++ $(INC) -std=gnu++11 $(SOURCES) -g -o myexe -lpthread -Wall -lgstapp-1.0 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
clean:
    rm -rf *.o myexe
```

But I wrote the same in my .pro file in Qt creator and I get an error:

```
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/gst/gstelement.h:55:  gst/gstconfig.h: No such file or directory
```

This is my full .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/ \
/usr/include/glib-2.0/ \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ \
/usr/include/libxml2/

LIBS += -std=gnu++11
LIBS += -lgstapp-1.0
LIBS += -lpthread
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs  gstreamer-1.0`

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Please tell, how to fix this ? I really want to use Qt creator.

Comment: Are you aware that you can call `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` on shell prompt and look what it does generate? May be, it produces additional include paths...

Comment: AFAIK, these ...config.h files are not necessarily stored where the other include files are. Probably, because they may be generated in some kind of "configuration build". I would guess you need an additional include path and you should be able to find this out like I recommended in my previous comment. (If I'm right you may provide this as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I cannot reproduce locally but I'm curious.)

Comment: hey, you are right! I executed this command and I saw a few other paths. I added into .pro file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct .pro file with all needed paths:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/ \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include \
/usr/include/glib-2.0/ \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ \
/usr/include/libxml2/

LIBS += -std=gnu++11
LIBS += -lgstapp-1.0
LIBS += -lpthread
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs  gstreamer-1.0`

SOURCES += main.cpp
```